# Fluid grid height animation UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I have to create an animation of the height of a grid (this with the db data of the microphone, I have simulated the reception of the data with a random). But the animation I created is not fluid at all. How can I get an animation to make an example like google assistant (google play app) with four colored bars (I mean that as fluid animation)?

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ColorGrid" Background="Blue" Height="150" Width="40" CornerRadius="20"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
DispatcherTimer TimerHeight = new DispatcherTimer();
Storyboard storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
double AnimationTime = 50;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    TimerHeight.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
    TimerHeight.Tick += TimerHeight_Tick;
    TimerHeight.Start();
}

private void TimerHeight_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    double ActualHeight = GetRandomNumber(150,350);
    //ColorGrid.Height = ActualHeight;
    StartAnimation(ColorGrid, ActualHeight);
}

public double GetRandomNumber(double minimum, double maximum)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.NextDouble() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
}

private void StartAnimation(Grid GridColor, double GridHight)
{
    storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
    var AnimationOne = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(AnimationTime)), Value = GridHight, EasingFunction = new QuarticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut } };
    var AnimOne = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    AnimOne.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    AnimOne.KeyFrames.Add(AnimationOne);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimOne, "(FrameworkElement.Height)");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(AnimOne, GridColor);
    storyboard1.Children.Add(AnimOne);
    storyboard1.Begin();
}
```

Although I have used an animation it is as if there are shots. How can I get smooth animation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran your code and it performed fine for me. What do you mean by "not fluid"? Can you expand on this a little bit and maybe show a gif or video of your end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although I have used an animation it is as if there are shots. How can I get smooth animation?

If you want to make animation smoothly, you could set `AnimationTime`([`KeyTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.keytime)) bigger.

For my testing, if you set AnimationTime  as 600, the animation will be very smooth.

```
private void StartAnimation(Grid GridColor, double GridHight)
{
    storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
    var AnimationOne = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)),
        Value = GridHight,
        EasingFunction = new QuarticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut } };
    var AnimOne = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    AnimOne.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    AnimOne.KeyFrames.Add(AnimationOne);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimOne, "(FrameworkElement.Height)");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(AnimOne, GridColor);
    storyboard1.Children.Add(AnimOne);
    storyboard1.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to our beautiful community!

First, have you tried to run the app WITHOUT the all Visual Studio's Debug system?
Because it is heavy and may cause animations to not be fluid... I have also experienced that sometime.
So, first thing to do, is to deploy your app and then run it just by clicking on it as if it was installed from the store.

Second... aren't you trying to animate too many animations in so few millis?
Try to set the `TimeSpan` a little bit longer (e.g. 1000) and see what happens...

Comment: The example to which I referred is much more fluid, and in the question I do not say that my animation is the solution but I look for an alternative solution. Setting the timespan to 1000 is like a delay of one second.